# Xcode: Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT

Tags: xcode, sigabrt

I am very new to Xcode and its language and I am trying to make a simple calculator and after adding more view I get this error "Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT" and the app wont open in iOS Simulator. The error points to this line of code:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

I tried searching before but I didn't understand what the other answers were talking about.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWKBg.png

Here is a screenshot of what comes up when I attempt to run the program

Comment: Go to the Breakpoint Navigator and add an exception breakpoint.  When you get an error, Xcode should then stop at the place where the error was generated and show you a stack trace.  If the trace doesn't make sense to you, post it as part of your question and someone is likely to have better suggestions for you.  The line you're seeing now is not useful because it's really just saying, "something bad happened inside the app".

Comment: I added a screenshot because I am not sure what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That mean´s you call a method or something other stuff that not exists. 
[Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) has a good tutorial. Can you post the message from the console?